# Unable to install PyAudio in Python 3.9 (Windows, Ubuntu)

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

I'm trying to install PyAudio on Python 3.9. I am running Windows 10 and using an Ubuntu bash. I've tried both `pip3 install` and `pip3 install pyasn‑1.6.0b1‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`. The second being an attempt to use the unofficial 3.9 wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).

This is what I get when I attempt `pip3 install pyaudio`:

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-imufkwd7/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-imufkwd7/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-c2o57hhw
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-imufkwd7/pyaudio/
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
     29 | #include "portaudio.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-imufkwd7/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-imufkwd7/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8vw48w5x/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/lukangel00/.local/include/python3.8/pyaudio
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-imufkwd7/pyaudio/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
       29 | #include "portaudio.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-imufkwd7/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-imufkwd7/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8vw48w5x/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/lukangel00/.local/include/python3.8/pyaudio Check the logs for full command output.
```

In the error message, I'm noticing a reference to Python 3.8, which I don't have. Is this part of the error?

And this is what I get when I attempt `pip3 install pyasn‑1.6.0b1‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`:

```
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I've checked, and I'm certain that I have x64 Python. I also tried a different version in case this one was buggy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing python-dev

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0`

try the above snippet before running

`pip install pyaudio`

it worked for me

here are some sources I took this info in case you need it:

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+install+pyaudio+in+ubuntu

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/974/how-to-solve-installation-error-of-pyaudio-in-ubuntu-18-04-fatal-error-portaudio-h-file-not-found